# Docker container runs with docker-compose up but doesn't with docker run

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

First attempt into docker and I've hit a wall.
I don't understand how the docker works and when my local machine is "detached" from the container. At the end the project runs with docker-compose run, but doesn't with docker run because it cannot connect to postgres.

When I run docker-compose run with these settings everything works:

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
  celery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: common.env
    command: celery -A saleor worker --app=saleor.celeryconf:app --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - .:/app:Z
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
  search:
    image: elasticsearch:5.4.3
    mem_limit: 512m
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:9200:9200'
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file: common.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - search
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/app:Z
  makemigrations:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py makemigrations --noinput
    volumes:
      - .:/app:Z
  migration:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py migrate --noinput
    volumes:
      - .:/app:Z
```

However, if I run

1. docker build -t db_test .
2. docker run -p 4000:8000 db_test

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN \
  apt-get -y update && \
  apt-get install -y gettext && \
  apt-get clean

ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000
ENV PORT 8000

CMD ["uwsgi", "/app/saleor/wsgi/uwsgi.ini"]
```

I am getting an exception:

### OperationalError at / could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

If I change the DB settings to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '**localhost**',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

the build and run I get:

### could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

This is the postgres port on my machine. Then if I turn of postgres and the port is free nothing changes.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: if you want to not use the docker compose (that starts all your services db,web, etc) you have to start them manually, network them and link them to know each other. So when you started just the python container it doesn't know anything about your db container. I'm not familiar with the python image, do you have a server on it?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @EstebanGarcia MacOS

Comment: @Edwin Do mean I have to chain all the command in the CMD list?

Comment: the services -> no. You have to start them separately. As I said, I don't know what the python image has on it, if it has a db or not. But if it doesn't then what are you trying will not work, because there's no db.

Comment: Are you using docker-machine ?

Comment: No I am not. I might use it to deploy on digital ocean for the sake of it but, they have an app for docker and I am trying with it.

Comment: Then are you using the version of docker for macos that virtualizes using apple's hypervisor?

Comment: Yes that is the official one on their website.